# Vue.js v-model input value and populate existing data

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I have some data in an array that I want to populate from an input while looping through.

And also add more input in case I want to. I don't get any error, but the data is not being populated.

My script:

```
data() {
  return {
     meta: []
  }
}
```

My template:

```
<div class="field" v-for="(meta, index) in data.meta" : key="index">
  <input : v-model="data.meta[index]" name="type" class="form-control shadow-btn" />
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="addInput" > add</a >
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at your code, `:v-model="data.meta[index]"` should be the same as `:v-model="meta"`. Also, keep in mind that using the index as a key may create issues because the index of the elements in your list may change (if their position in the array changes)

Comment: So should I change my db structure to accept object or what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Your Template neet to be display so:

`<div class="field" v-for="(m, index) in meta" :key="index">
         <input :v-model="m" name="type" class="form-control shadow-btn" />
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this approach!**

```js
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data: {
        meta:['Meta 1','Meta 2']
    },
    methods: {
        addInput(){
            alert("Do something!");
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="field" v-for="(m, index) in meta" :key="index">
            <input :value="m" name="type" class="form-control shadow-btn" />
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="addInput">add</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```